# Show that $f(z)= \alpha z + \beta \bar{z}$ satisfy $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear $\iff$ $f(i)=if(1)$ $\iff$ $\beta=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

With the identification $\mathbb{R}^2 \equiv \mathbb{C}$, show that each function $\mathbb{R}$-linear $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ could be set uniquely as $f(z)= \alpha z +  \beta \bar{z}$ **(*)**, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

I found the system equation \begin{align*}
f(1) & = \alpha + \beta\\
f(i) & = i(\alpha - \beta)
\end{align*}

Question : Show that **(*)** satisfy $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear $\iff$ $f(i)=if(1)$ $\iff$ $\beta=0$

How could I prove this second part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, you can write it as
$$
f\colon\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. With the identification you have
$$
x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\quad y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}
$$
so
$$
f(z)=(ax+by)+i(cx+dy)
=a\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}+b\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}+
ic\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}+id\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}
$$
It takes some patience to simplify this into
$$
f(z)=\frac{a-b+ic+d}{2}z+\frac{a+ib+ic-d}{2}\bar{z}
$$

Conversely, if $f(z)=\alpha z+\beta\bar{z}$, you have
$$
f(1)=\alpha+\beta,\qquad f(i)=(\alpha-\beta)i
$$
Now write $\alpha=A+Bi$, $\beta=C+Di$ and find the matrix representation of $f$ as a map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, then
$$
(\alpha-\beta)i=f(i)=if(1)=i(\alpha+\beta)
$$
which implies…